# d3.symbols being cut off by ClipPath area

Tags: symbols, clip-path, d3.js

Still in the process of improving my competence about D3, I got stuck with a problem where I'm trying to plot a zoomable curve in a SVG element with margins (so that I need a clipPath rect to avoid that plot invades margins when zoomed) but the clipPath margins cut the display of d3.symbols off the plot.

This is the relevant code for the plot

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    w = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

// The curve I want to plot: y=x^2
var my_curve = d3.range(10).map(function(d) { var my_y = d * d; return { "x" : d, "y" : my_y }; });

var x_range_min = d3.min(my_curve, function(d) { return d.x; }); 
var x_range_max = d3.max(my_curve, function(d) { return d.x; });
var y_range_min = d3.min(my_curve, function(d) { return d.y; }); 
var y_range_max = d3.max(my_curve, function(d) { return d.y; });

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([x_range_min, x_range_max]).range([0, w]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([y_range_max, y_range_min]).range([0, h]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yScale);


// symbols
svg.selectAll(".my_pts").data(my_curve).enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "my_pts")
    .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolTriangle).size(200))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + xScale(d.x) + "," + yScale(d.y) + ")"; })
    // with this zoomed line does not enter margin area
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

...as you can see only part of the triangle symbol is depicted, I guess because the path is drawn at 0,0 and cut by the clipPath before the translation can be performed.

I have also posted this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fabio_p/988c1sjv/
where you can find a more complete version of the code, with the brush & zoom function, so that you can see why the clipPath is needed (if you have never encountered the issue with margins before)

My question is the following: is there a workaround to this problem? I was hoping to find a way to directly draw the symbol in the right place without the need of a later translation (possibly with a "custom symbol type"), but it seems it goes beyond my current skills, since I was unable to produce any actual solution.

Any suggestion would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a group with the clip path:

```
var clipping = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

And append both the line and the symbols to the group:

```
clipping.append("path")
    .data([my_curve])
    //etc...
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvtvrL2q/

Comment: Brilliant! This solution is simple and elegant!

From your suggestion however it seems that most of my "problems" originated from the <svg> design more than from d3: is there any good source of info about the order in which this kind of svg operations (clipping areas / transforming / etc.) take place? 
The W3C recommendation "...the given child element is clipped by the referenced clipping path before OR'ing [...] with the silhouettes of the other child elements" was not so self-explanatory to me and who knows if I'm still missing further details :-(

Comment: Well, I'm not the best person to guide you regarding this because I normally don't use clip paths in my graphs. Maybe you can post this issue as a new question using the "svg" tag only, that way the SVG gurus can help you. But you have to make a question about an actual code, not just "asking for a tutorial or best practices", otherwise they will close your question as off topic in seconds...